# Mongodb updates within a transaction

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, updates, document

I am trying to update a document from within a transaction. I am using 'findbyidandupdate' with a session object passed in, but I get this error:

```
MongooseError: Callback must be a function, got [object Object]
```

Related backend code in Node.js. The session object is created from a data model  object, in this case the data object is 'Device':

```
const session = await Device.startSession();

const transactionOptions = {
        readPreference: 'primary',
        readConcern: { level: 'local' },
        writeConcern: { w: 'majority' }
    };

const transactionResults = await session.withTransaction( async () => {
               const deviceUpdateResults = await 
    Device.findByIdAndUpdate(
                {session},
                (deviceid),
                {$push: {"reviews": (reviewid)}},
                { new : true, safe: true})
}
```

Looks like the method cannot accept a session object. How do I pass a session object to an update method?

Comment: could you please update your question with more details, 1) post your tried query 2) what is the session object, show what is in it 3) console your input 4) show expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Mongoose documentation, [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) has a different signature from the one you have used. First of all, `findByIdAndUpdate` is just an utility method that eventually calls [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L2691), as also pointed out in the documentation, so the arguments are basically the same.

The problem you have is that you are passing too many arguments: since you are using the `async` version of the function, you should pass at most 3 arguments. Instead, for the callback version, you need 4 arguments with the callback at the end.

This is how you should have called the `findByIdAndUpdate`:

```
const deviceUpdateResults = await Device.findByIdAndUpdate(
    deviceid,
    { $push: { "reviews": reviewid } },
    { session: session, new: true}
);
```

---

Few observations not really about your issue:

- I have always used the NodeJS native driver for MongoDB, so Mongoose is pretty unknown to me, but if you start a `ClientSession` with `startSession`, I expect you also need to close it with `endSession`. The alternative (for the native driver) is to use `withSession` that accepts a callback where the session is valid.
- As for now, `readPreference: 'primary'` can be omitted because the transaction can only happen in the primary. The default `readConcern` is `local`, so you could omit that too.
- Isn't `safe` option deprecated? It is not even listed in the documentation anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to make your code a bit simpler.
Do try this

```
await Device.updateOne({_id:_id},{$push:{"reviews":reviewId});
```

Where the first parameter filters the data and second one update the data

Comment: didn't passed the {session}, will run out of the transaction.